# VS2013: How to rename a file from within the file contents window using only the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have changed the name of a C# class in my application and as I use one class per file as a personal convention I'd also like to rename the file itself. I avoid using the mouse while programming but every time I have to popup the Solution Explorer (I leave it hidden), look for the file and rename it there, so much effort for a simple task. I tried to find a way to rename the file from within the file content window itself but could not, and couldn't find an answer if this is possible or not.

Does anyone know if this is possible? And if it is, how can this be done? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the filename in the Solution Explorer instead of the class name in the editor, Visual Studio asks you if you also want to rename the class.

If that's not what you want you can open up the Solution Explorer with `Ctrl + ;`. If you check the option Track Active Item (Tools -> Projects and Solutions -> General), VS will automatically jump to the current file. If that's a little to much, there is a Sync button at the top of the Solution Explorer that you activate with `Ctrl + [,S`. Renaming a file is done with `F2`.